# Deployer extension | failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.tridion.storage.BinaryMeta.binaryVariants, no session or session was closed

Tags: 2013-sp1, deployer-extension

I am updating an existing deployer extension to implement Akamai fast purge.
before my implementation, it was working perfectly fine.
post-deployment of new deployer extension it was started showing following error whenever any binary/component presentation has been published.

Following is stack trace for binary:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.tridion.storage.BinaryMeta.binaryVariants, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:393) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:378) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-4.0.1.final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.metlife.deployer.extensions.akamai.AkamaiDeployProcessor.postProcessComponentPresentation(AkamaiDeployProcessor.java:109) ~[metlife-add-marketing-deployer-india.jar:na]
    at com.metlife.deployer.extensions.AkamaiDeployProcessorBase.processComponentPresentation(AkamaiDeployProcessorBase.java:33) [metlife-add-marketing-deployer-india.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy.processItem(ComponentPresentationDeploy.java:105) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:77) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180) [cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

Following is the code segment from where this error has been generated:

```
package com.metlife.deployer.extensions.akamai;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.metlife.deployer.extensions.AkamaiDeployProcessorBase;
import com.metlife.deployer.extensions.constants.Constants;
import com.metlife.deployer.extensions.restclient.AkamaiRestClient;
import com.metlife.deployer.extensions.restclient.impl.AkamaiRestClientImpl;
import com.metlife.deployer.extensions.util.URLCreator;
import com.tridion.broker.StorageException;
import com.tridion.configuration.Configuration;
import com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import com.tridion.deployer.Processor;
import com.tridion.storage.BinaryContent;
import com.tridion.storage.BinaryMeta;
import com.tridion.storage.BinaryVariant;
import com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory;
import com.tridion.storage.StorageTypeMapping;
import com.tridion.storage.dao.ItemDAO;
import com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.BinaryKey;
import com.tridion.transport.transportpackage.ComponentPresentation;

/**
 * This is subclass of MetlifeDeployProcessorBase.
 * 
 * @author sgup42
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AkamaiDeployProcessor extends AkamaiDeployProcessorBase {
    /** Instance of URLCreator. */
    private URLCreator urlCreator = null;

    /** Instance of AkamaiRestClient. */
    private AkamaiRestClient akamaiRestClient = null;

    /** LOGGER Instance */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(AkamaiDeployProcessor.class);

    /**
     * Constructor for AkamaiDeployProcessor.
     * 
     * @param config
     *            - Instance of Configuration
     * @param processor
     *            - Instance of Processor
     * @throws ConfigurationException
     *             - Instance of ConfigurationException.
     */
    public AkamaiDeployProcessor(Configuration config, Processor processor)
            throws ConfigurationException {
        super(config, processor);
    }

    /**
     * This is an overridden implementation for
     * "postProcessComponentPresentation",it captures the "publicationId" and
     * "itemId" of the binary component. It gets the path of all the published
     * multimedia components and sends the list to Akamai.
     */
    @Override
    public void postProcessComponentPresentation(
            ComponentPresentation componentPresentation,
            File comPresentationFile) {
        LOGGER.debug(Constants.METHOD_START);

        try {
            LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| method start");
            int publicationId = componentPresentation.getComponentKey().getId()
                    .getPublicationId();
            BinaryKey binaryKey = null;
            LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id :" + publicationId);
            List urlList = new ArrayList();
            for (Iterator binaryKeysIterator = componentPresentation
                    .getBinaryKeys(); binaryKeysIterator.hasNext();) {
                LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 83");

                binaryKey = (BinaryKey) binaryKeysIterator.next();
                LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 86");

                byte[] content = {};
                BinaryContent binaryContent = new BinaryContent(publicationId,
                        binaryKey.getId().getItemId(),
                        binaryKey.getVariantId(), content);
                LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 92");

                ItemDAO item = (ItemDAO) StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(
                        publicationId, StorageTypeMapping.BINARY_META);
                LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 96");

                BinaryMeta binaryMeta = (BinaryMeta) item
                        .findBinaryByPrimaryKey(
                                binaryContent.getPublicationId(),
                                binaryContent.getBinaryId());
                LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 102");

                if (binaryMeta != null) {
                    List BinaryVariantList = binaryMeta
                            .getBinaryVariants();
                    LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 107");

                    **for (Iterator iterator2 = BinaryVariantList.iterator(); iterator2
                            .hasNext();) {
                        BinaryVariant binaryVariant = (BinaryVariant) iterator2
                                .next();**
                        LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| URL is :" + binaryVariant.getPath()
                                + " for Binary type :"
                                + binaryVariant.getBinaryType());
                        LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 116");

                        urlList.add(binaryVariant.getPath());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!urlList.isEmpty()) {
                LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| Calling AkamaiRestClient to create purge request. 123");
                List purgeUrls = new ArrayList();
                urlCreator = new URLCreator();
                purgeUrls = urlCreator.createPurgeURL(urlList);
                this.akamaiRestClient = new AkamaiRestClientImpl();
                this.akamaiRestClient.purgeResources(purgeUrls);

            }
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| Error occured while postProcessComponentPresentation: storage", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| Error occured while postProcessComponentPresentation: ", e);
        }
        LOGGER.debug(Constants.METHOD_END);
    }

}
```

from multiple log statements i can see that following log statement was last executed:
*LOGGER.debug("AkamaiDeployProcessor.java | postProcessComponentPresentation()| publication_id : 107");*

I have updated following jar files as old jar files are not working with current implementation:

1. hibernate-core-4.0.1.final.jar
2. slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
3. httpcore-4.4.4.jar
4. httpclient-4.5.8.jar
5. commons-logging-1.2.jar
6. commons-lang3-3.4.jar
7. commons-configuration2-2.1.jar
8. commons-codec-1.11.jar
9. cd_model-7.0.0.jar
10. cd_deployer-7.0.0.jar
11. cd_datalayer-7.0.0.jar

I am using Tridion 2013 SP1 and JDK 1.7

following is cd_deployer config

```
    <!-- <Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction"> -->

    <Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
        <!-- A Module is triggered by a Processor to process incoming instructions.
                The 'Type' attribute needs to be unique within a Processor and serves
                as a symbolic identifier. The 'Class' attribute defines the
                implementation used for any type of Module. Replace or add modules to
                implement custom Deployer behavior. -->
        <Module Type="ApplicationCacheFlushForComponentPresentation" Class="com.******.deployer.extensions.ehcache.ApplicationCacheFlushForComponentPresentation" />
        <Module Type="ApplicationCacheFlushForTaxonomy" Class="com.******.deployer.extensions.ehcache.ApplicationCacheFlushForTaxonomy" />
        <Module Type="AkamaiDeploy" Class="com.******.deployer.extensions.akamai.AkamaiDeployProcessor" />
        <Module Type="SchemaDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy"/>
        <Module Type="PageDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy">
            <!-- The transformer enables the TCDL Engine -->
            <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
        </Module>
        <Module Type="BinaryDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy"/>
        <Module Type="ComponentDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy"/>
        <Module Type="TemplateDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy"/>
        <Module Type="PublicationDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy"/>

        <!-- This module enables deployment of taxonomies -->
        <Module Type="TaxonomyDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy"/>

        <Module Type="ComponentPresentationDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy">
            <!-- The transformer enables the TCDL Engine -->
            <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>
        </Module>

        <!-- This module enables deployment of structure groups -->
        <Module Type="StructureGroupDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy"/>
        <!-- This module enables the deploy of extension data. This module should be enabled if you are using UNDO -->
        <!-- <Module Type="ExtensionDataDeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ExtensionDataDeploy"/> -->
    </Processor>
    <Processor Action="Undeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
        <Module Type="PageUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy"/>
        <Module Type="ComponentPresentationUndeploy"
                Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy"/>

        <!-- This module enables the undeploy of taxonomies -->
        <Module Type="TaxonomyUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy"/>

        <!-- This module enables the undeploy of structure groups -->
        <Module Type="StructureGroupUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy"/>

        <!-- This module enables the undeploy of extension data. This module should be enabled if you are using UNDO -->
        <!-- <Module Type="ExtensionDataUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.modules.ExtensionDataUndeploy"/> -->
    </Processor>

    <!-- Undo Deployer modules.-->
    <!--
    <Processor Action="Undo" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor">
      <Module Type="UndoModule" Class="com.tridion.deployer.UndoDeploy"/>
    </Processor>
    -->
    <!-- Undo Deployer module for post-transaction should be enabled only if there are any deployer post-transaction modules configured.-->
    <!--
    <Processor Action="Undo" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction">
      <Module Type="UndoModule" Class="com.tridion.deployer.UndoPostTransactionDeploy"/>
    </Processor>
    -->
    <!-- Undo Deployer module for pre-transaction should be enabled only if there are any deployer pre-transaction modules configured.-->
    <!--
    <Processor Action="Undo" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="pre-transaction">
      <Module Type="UndoModule" Class="com.tridion.deployer.UndoPreTransactionDeploy"/>
    </Processor>
    -->

</Processors>
<!-- Configure the Queue locations the deployer checks for incoming deployment packages -->
<Queue>
    <Location Path="/opt/adam/tridion/cda-india/incoming" WindowSize="20" Workers="10" Cleanup="false" Interval="2s"/>
    <!--<Location Path="c:\tridion\work\http" WindowSize="10" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="30s"/> -->
</Queue>
<!-- Configure the HTTPSReceiver to store incoming package in specified location, and configure if deployer should run in process -->
<HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="209715200" Location="/opt/adam/tridion/cda-india/incoming" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
<!--
 Specifies the location of the license file.
 -->
<!--
 <License Location="c:/Tridion/config/cd_licenses.xml"/>
 -->

<TCDLEngine>
    <Properties>
        <!-- Default code generation will always be targetted towards the use of tag libraries and
              server controls. Uncomment these lines to drop that behaviour -->
        <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="controls"/>
        <Property Name="tcdl.jsp.style" Value="tags"/>

        <!-- Since R5.4 another interop mechanism for ASP.NET has been introduced this setting
           will allow code generation into that new Interop model. -->
        <!-- <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="native_interop" /> -->

        <!-- To use the deprecated R5.3 code generation enable this line -->
        <!-- <Property Name="tcdl.dotnet.style" Value="com_interop" /> -->

        <!--To fix the target language to a specific language uncomment any of the following lines -->
        <!--<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="jsp" />-->
        <!--<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="dotnet" />-->
        <!--<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel" />-->
        <!--Deprecated: <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="vbscript" />-->
        <!--Deprecated: <Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="jscript" />-->
    </Properties>
    <!--
    Optional configuration needed in case of using the UGC TCDL transformers
    -->
    <!--
    <TagBundle Resource="ugc_tag_bundle.xml"/>
    -->
</TCDLEngine>

<!--
 Specify RMI listening port
 -->
<!--
 <RMIChannel ListenerPort="1050"/>
 -->
```

Regards,
Soumava

Comment: Can you please edit your question to update the full class source? also, update the cd_deployer_conf.xml of Processor tag?

Comment: Hi @Velmurugan, due to character limitation posting class file as part of original question.